# How do I know the number of seconds remaining until the alarm goes off?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

**Scenario**

i am developing an app that works kind of like subscription, i start an alarm manager for days, suppose the alarm manager has started yesterday and it should go off tomorrow, how do i know exact time remaining till alarm manager goes off?

```
// ALARM_MANAGER setting to expired
SharedPreferences alarmpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor alarmEditor = alarmpreferences.edit();
alarmEditor.putString("ALARM_MANAGER", "active");
alarmEditor.apply();

AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), mainAlarmRequestCode, i,
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Start 20 seconds after boot completed
int secondTime = Integer.parseInt(expireTime)*60;
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, secondTime);
//
// Fetch every 20 seconds
// InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
```

I check to see if the alarm manager is running in  the 0  background with this method.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), mainAlarmRequestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);


if (alarmUp) {
   Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
   Toast.makeText(this, "alarm manager is active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//alarm is active check alarm manager counter time


} else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "alarm manager is not active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

The alarm manager is active, but how do I know the number of seconds remaining until the alarm goes off?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AlarmManager: how to find out the time remaining to trigger the PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387819/android-alarmmanager-how-to-find-out-the-time-remaining-to-trigger-the-pendingi)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the expiration date of your `AlarmManager` and run a test at regular interval, to check if the current date is greater than the expiration one.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i don't want to run any background service as it consumes battery! i wanted to know if there's a method on which we can get alarm manager remaining time.

Comment: As per the documentation, there isn't such a method to do what you want to achieve. However, if you want to have the remaining time only once, you can read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493985/5455101

Comment: ok thanks, i am doing research to find out a solution or workaround.